Any issues with changing IP address on newly configured domain controller?
In the middle of replacing an old DC with a new one running Windows Server 2022.
Just about everything is done on the new server, DHCP, DNS, roles transferred, etc. and the new DC is replicating without issue.
The last thing I want to do is change the IP address of the new DC to the IP address of the old DC so I don't have to whack a mole with every thing that references that IP for DNS, etc.
I know renaming the new DC to the old DC causes a ton of problems but are there any if you just flip the IPs and then demote the old server?
What would be the correct order, demote/flip, flip/demote?  I am not looking to flip the FQDNs.
Thanks in advance.

Might be simpler to keep the new IP address, and when the old server has been demoted and is gone, bind its IP as secondary to your new server.

@Zac67 that could work, thanks for the suggestion

As long as DNS is updated, changing IP is no problem with AD.
AD is heavily reliant on DNS for discovery, but it does not rely on IP's staying constant.

Right, I figured once the old DC is demoted and its IP changed to something else, it should be cleared from everything involving AD and then it's just a matter of the new DC registering that IP.  Or something like that.

You could check that there's no lingering SRV records in DNS, but apart from that...
